# The Image is not getting uploaded in Flask app

Tags: html, flask

My code is running fine, And yet I'm still unable to load the images on my flask app. Can someone help me to figure out the error in code?

I want the image first, then the scraped test to be displayed.

**app.py**

```
from flask import Flask,render_template
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

app=Flask(__name__,static_folder='C:\\Users\HP\OneDrive\Desktop\scraper\static')

@app.route('/index',methods=["GET","POST"])
def index():
  url="https://www.businesstoday.in/technology/news"
  req=requests.get(url)
  soup=BeautifulSoup(req.content,"html.parser")
  outerdata=soup.find_all("div",class_="widget-listing",limit=6)

  finalnews=""

  for data in outerdata:
     news=data.div.div.a['title']
     finalnews+="\u2022"+news+'\n'

  return render_template("index.html",News=finalnews)

if __name__=="__main__":
  app.run()
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE-edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width-device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>TEchify</title>
</head>   
<body>
    <div  style="width: 614px ; height: 700px;" >
       <img src="/static/image/7.jpg">
        <span>{{News|safe}}</span>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

once you load an html from a website you will see that the image sources don't have long URLs, they have local URLs instead. Such as `/static/duck.png`. What you need to do is, check the sources with dev tools in your browser. And then algorithmically add base URLs to short URLs. Example: `https://example.com/static/duck.png`


You can do this in order to add base URLs to image sources:

```
baseURL='https://example.com'
imageHTML = '<img src="/static/duck.png"/>'


def changeImageSource(baseURL,html):
    return html.replace('src="',f'src="{baseURL}')

imageHTML = changeImageSource(baseURL,imageHTML)

#OUTPUT
#'<img src="https://example.com/static/duck.png"/>'
```

**NOTE**
You need to check if the sources are starting with / or not, if they are not you need to use the current page's url as a base with extra /.